# How can I move to word-level perplexities?

Tags: python, nlp, tensorflow

I've built a *next character predictor* neural network in TensorFlow loosely based on [char-rnn-tensorflow](https://github.com/sherjilozair/char-rnn-tensorflow). As a result, I am successfully able to calculate the probability distribution of the next character given a test sequence.

Taking an average across all the `log` probabilities, I can successfully get the "character level perplexity". I've pretty much used the code in this [pull request](https://github.com/sherjilozair/char-rnn-tensorflow/pull/56/files) to achieve this.

However, I would need to move to "word level perplexities", since I need to compare my model with standard results, most of which report the effectiveness of a language model based on "word level perplexities". (Wikipedia describes word level perplexities [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perplexity#Perplexity_per_word))

What's the correct way to do this? Is it even possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Character-level language models (LM) are different from word-level LMs. What you have trained is a character level LM, and as far as I am concern, you should not compare a character-level LM and word-level LM directly using perplexity.

However, if you have an neural network architecture for language modeling, you can use it to train a character-level LM and a word-level LM and compare your models with the existing character-level LMs and a word-level LMs respectively using perplexity (the competing models should be trained/tested on the same dataset).

This code is similar to the one you used, but for word-level modeling: https://github.com/hunkim/word-rnn-tensorflow

Comment: The issue is that I never see perplexity reports for character level LMs

Comment: You are right, it is more common to see word-based perplexity. However, there are works that report character perplexity: https://www.transacl.org/ojs/index.php/tacl/article/download/865/211 or http://www.fit.vutbr.cz/~imikolov/rnnlm/char.pdf

Comment: Could I find an exhaustive list of works that report character perplexities like these two? Thank you!

Comment: I don't think you can find an exhaustive list. You probably need to do some research using google and the references of the known papers.

Comment: Thank you so much!